# SQL code subtraction

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to get the SQL code for "Number of available seats on flight `F1000` on `10/10/2014`.

But I am confused on how to minus off the capacity with the seats.

My table are as followed:

**Plane**

```
PK-PlaneSerial
Capacity
```

**Schedule**

```
PK-RouteID
PK-FlightDate
FK-PlaneSerial
ScheduleTime
```

**Reservation**

```
PK-ResID
PK,FK-RouteID
FK - FLightDate
Price
```

I know i will need to subtract my Plane Capacity with the total number of reservation but have received error.
Anyone have any Idea?

Comment: Edit your question and add the query that is returning an error.  Also, explain what the error is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT s.RouteID, (MAX(p.Capacity) - p.Capacity) AS Numbofavailableseats
FROM Plane p
INNER JOIN Schedule s ON p.PlaneSerial = s.PlaneSerial
INNER JOIN Reservation r ON s.RouteID = r.RouteID
WHERE s.RouteID = 'F1000' AND s.FlightDate = '10/10/2014'
```

Comment: thank you but i've got this error 
`Error at line 1, column 19:
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression`

Comment: try now with diffeent brackets

Comment: this would work only under the assumption that every reservation has only one seat associated to it. If that is not the case, the table structure need to be revisited

Comment: yeh, but other than that i dont know how the users data is built up

Comment: @shankar yup assuming 1 seat per reservation

Comment: the error is because you can't fetch p.Capacity without group by this column

Comment: On Oracle, you can't have a column in the `select` clause that is not either inside a aggregate function or in the `GROUP BY` clause. Try `max(p.capacity)`

Comment: max(capacity) erase the error, but could give wrong results i think

Comment: I was assuming p.capacity was the capacity of the plane, not how many were on board. @XGAl can you confirm?

Comment: i've added p.capacity in the `GROUP BY` which solved the error
will do some testing 
Thanks so much!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted!

Comment: @matt thanks for your help!! it seems okay after testing